# View not updating on observable changed

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I'm trying to have a list be rerendered when the container of the list is updated:

```
{^{for selectedScenario.instances}}
     <div>{^{:name}}</div>
{{/for}}
```

When I use $.observable(data).setProperty("selectedScenario", scenario), nothing changes. In http://jsfiddle.net/ep76m4af/1/ you can see this in action. ObserveAll shows that the data itself is updated and the event is properly fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you are using a 'deep path' `selectedScenario.instances` - which by default 'listens' to observable changes only at the leaf level, not deeper. To opt in to listening also to changes in the `selectedScenario` object, not just the leaf `instances` property, you need to replace the `.` by `^` to indicate that you want to listen down to a deeper level in the path:

```
{^{for selectedScenario^instances}}
     <div>{^{:name}}</div>
{{/for}}
```

See the section *Paths: leaf changes or deep changes* in this documentation topic:
http://www.jsviews.com/#observe.

See also the examples such as *Example: JsViews with plain objects and array* in this topic: http://www.jsviews.com/#explore/objectsorvm.

Updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ep76m4af/2/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the examples and documentation regarding the deep paths. I read it before but it was a lot to take so I forgot that part..