# JsObservable setting Property with Child Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, observable, jsviews, data-linking

How would I go about making an observable update to an object with child properties data-linked to form elements?

```js
var app = {
    formData: {
        selectedThing: "thingValue1",
        selectedPlace: "placeValue1"
    }
};



$("#btnUpdate").on("click", function(){
    var replacementForm = {
        selectedThing: "thingValue2",
        selectedPlace: "placeValue2"
    }
    $.observable(app).setProperty("formData", replacementForm);
});

$("#content").link(true, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <input data-link="formData.selectedThing trigger=true"/>
    <br/>
    <input data-link="formData.selectedPlace trigger=true"/>
</div>

<button id="btnUpdate" type="button">Update</button>
```

I have some input fields data-linked to properties of an object, and when the user presses a button, all of those fields need to get updated using an object (received from the server as JSON, deserialized into an object identical to the data object underlying the form elements.)  Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xpe1ds0a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 'cloned' from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32339038/1054484

The reason it is not working is because you are using a 'deep path' `formData.selectedThing` - which by default 'listens' to observable changes only at the leaf level, not deeper. To opt in to listening also to changes in the `formData` object, not just the leaf `selectedThing` property, you need to replace the `.` by `^` to indicate that you want to listen down to a deeper level in the path:

```
<input data-link="formData.selectedThing trigger=true"/>
<input data-link="formData.selectedPlace trigger=true"/>
```

See the section *Paths: leaf changes or deep changes* in this documentation topic:
http://www.jsviews.com/#observe.

See also the examples such as *Example: JsViews with plain objects and array* in this topic: http://www.jsviews.com/#explore/objectsorvm.

Updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xpe1ds0a/1/

Comment: Would there be an easy way to remove the extraneous "jQuery#" property that the observable subscription "^" creates when used on the root object to make this example work? I'm unable to send formData to the server because the JSON object suddenly doesn't match the datacontract.

Comment: JSON.stringify(object) will strip the jQuery expando properties. See https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/71, and also https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/239, for some details.